# Directing to a Second Menu on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application

I'm very new to Android programming and working on Android Studio. I want to go to a second menu by clicking on a button and I will need these kind of stuff during my development. Is there any good tutorial that you know for Java for Android? Android's own tutorial is not very sufficient and there are lots of tutorials about android but all of them are very complex. I'm looking for something like android for dummies or something :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has the concept of Fragments and Activites for different views.

The Android training guide by google is really superb for the basics and have the sample code too, you should start from there

For the different views, here is a guide for that using fragments
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html